# MMS Listener for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, listener, mms

Is there any good tutorials/resources focusing on creating MMS LISTENER for iOS platform(XCode4)? MMS LISTENER is used on the client-side where the client will listen for any incoming MMS(image) to receive and suppress the MMS to check for any malicious data.

Comment: iOS is a closed platform. 98% of the telephony and messaging API are private.

Answer (score 0):

You can't intercept incoming MMS if you're thinking to submit the app on the store. You have to implement all your system from scratch(back-end and client-side), like "what's app messenger".

Comment: so for now its just to use the listener to receive MMS, then transfer it to an app while suppressing for notifications. is there any recommended tutorials/ways that could be of help?