# Is this implying its possible to intercept an SMS/MMS

Tags: ios

Is the reply to this posting suggesting that it is possible to intercept an MMS, provided you implement client side and back end?

[MMS Listener for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715998/mms-listener-for-ios)

"You can't intercept incoming MMS if you're thinking to submit the app on the store. You have to implement all your system from scratch(back-end and client-side), like "what's app messenger"."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not suggesting that.  It says that you have no access to the MMS sending or receiving functions on iOS, so if you want to send or receive MMS, you will have to do it by relaying the messages via your own server out on the Internet, and it will be completely independent of iOS's built-in messaging.

Comment: Can you expand upon what you mean by relaying the messages via your own server please. If I have both an app client on the iPhone and a server on the internet (and indeed actually access to an SMS/MMS gateway) what am I able to achieve in terms of supplying stuff from the server to the app?

Comment: That is a totally different question than your original question.

Comment: In what way? Intercepting an MMS on the device is the same as sending data from a server to a client if the server is the sender of the MMS. Anyway what did you mean by relaying messages? How is that related to interception of MMSs?

Comment: Intercepting an MMS on the device is **not** the same as sending data from a server to a client.  The question you referenced asked about intercepting the MMS messages sent by the cellular network to the device.  Those messages are handled by iOS and third-party apps cannot intercept them.  If you write an iPhone app that connects to your own server, your server can send whatever it wants to your app.  If your server has its own phone number, it can receive MMS messages sent to that number, convert them to HTML (or whatever you want), and send them to your app.